# Give DFA accepting the following languages

Tags: formal-languages, automata

[image] over the alphabet {0,1}

a) L = { w $\in$ {0,1}$^*$ | |w|$_{0} \leq$ 2 }

b) L = { w  $\in$ {0,1}$^*$ | w ends with 0}

over the alphabet {a,b,c}

L = { w $\in$ {a,b,c}$^*$ | |w|$_{ab}$ = 0 mod 2 and |w|$_{c} \geq$ 1 }

My work so far:

So I solved a) and b). But c) is really a problem. I've tried so many things but nothing worked. I will upload now my work a),b) and c). And like I said: I know that my c) isnt correct. Please help me and thank you in advance.

**Remark**: |w|$_{a}$ counts the letter a in w.

Comment: Sorry, but its too hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For c) consider the DFAs for the two following languages : $\left\{w\in\{a,b,c\}: |a|_{ab} \equiv 0 \mod 2\right\}$ and $\left\{w\in\{a,b,c\}: |a|_{c} \ge 1\right\}$.

Then consider combining the DFAs into their *cartesian product*.  The states are pairs $z=(x,y)$ where $x$  is a state of the first DFA and y a state of the second DFA.  A transition from $z_1=(x_1,y_1)$ to $z_2$ on character $\xi$ occurs if there was a transition from $x_1$ to $x_2$ on $\xi$ *and* a transition from $y_1$ to $y_2$ on $\xi$.  Trim out unreachable states, possibly simplify if needed and voilà.

This little operation, the cartesian product, is actually a way to follow two DFAs at the same time.  While parsing a string, instead of registering one state, you register two states, one for the left DFA and one for the right DFA.  But you can view the pair of states as a single state in itself and simplify that DFA as usual.